# Как зафиксировать фон с помощью JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Когда я изменяю фон сайта с помощью `JS`, то не могу его зафиксировать.

```
 document.body.style.background = 'url(https://pp.userapi.com/c837533/v837533109/6523e/oNQmDDB0a-A.jpg)';
```

т.е. он повторяется при прокручивании.. как прописать в `JS`, чтобы фон был фиксированным при прокрутке? В `Css` к `Body` всё прописано.

Comment: Если ответ помог решить вашу проблему, вы можете отметить его принятым, нажав на галочку рядом с ним.

Answer (score 4):

Это происходит, потому что через `style.background` вы меняете все свойства фона, таким образом переписывая и значение `background-attachment`.

Вместо этого нужно использовать `style.backgroundImage`:

```js
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://pp.userapi.com/c837533/v837533109/6523e/oNQmDDB0a-A.jpg)';
```

```css
body {
  background-position: center top;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height: 2000px;
}
```